# Problems installing "rails" in Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, ubuntu

I am new to programming and trying to install Rails on `Ubuntu 18.10`, but I get the following error when running `~$ gem install rails`. How do I avoid this error and install rails?

> ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
>       Permission denied @ dir_s_mkdir - /home/bernardo/.gem/specs

I'm running `Ruby 2.5.3p105`.

Comment: Howdy, looks like your issue is related to permissions on your system.  You could get around that by running sudo in front of your command.  However i think your best course of action is to remove ruby from your system (sudo apt-get purge ruby) and then start over with rbenv.  https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv

Comment: You almost certainly did `sudo gem install` on some other gem previously, and now your `/home/bernardo/.gem` directory is owned by `root`. The easiest way to fix this is a bit of a sledgehammer, but you should do it: `sudo rm -rf ~/.gem`, and then reinstall any gems you want. This will delete all your gems (some of which are owned by root), but it'll fix your problem. Just do that and then reinstall the gems you want, and never ever `sudo gem install` for any reason.

Comment: @Austio above is on the right track, but wrong about the underlying cause, and purging/reinstalling Ruby is not going to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the steps that I took to install rbenv in ubuntu server

```
git clone https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv.git ~/.rbenv
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
git clone https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build
rbenv -v
rbenv install 2.5.3
rbenv global 2.5.3
rbenv rehash
ruby -v
gem install bundler
# inside rails application
bundle install
```

Explanation:

- Line 1: clone rbenv project
- line 2-4: enter rbenv path and settings to your bashrc
- rbenv -v = check whether your rbenv is running correctly
- then install ruby version (I checked above you running version 2.5.3)
- rbenv global 2.5.3 (set version 2.5.3 in any folder paths)
- rbenv rehash (after you set global / local make sure you do rehash)

Answer (score 0):

Just go through the steps given in below link: https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/16.04
and make sure you install ruby using rvm and set is default ruby. Then install rails.
This will resolve your issue.

If still the problem is not resolved, then remove previously installed ruby and go through all the steps for ruby and rails installation.

Answer (score 0):

Never install a gem with sudo command.

use

```
gem install rails
```

instead of

```
sudo gem install rails
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `sudo gem install rails` May helps you.